# Will my Mac Pro be able to run WebGL applications?

Tags: macos, hardware, mac-pro, gpu, webgl

I've got a 2007 MacPro, 8GB RAM, 2 x NVIDIA GeForce 7300 GT (256 MB). I tried to look at a couple of Google's WebGL demos, for example this one but am unable to do so because my system is not WebGL compatible.

I'm running Lion and the latest version of Chrome - what else do I need to do? Will upgrading my GPUs work?

Or is my 'bleeding-edge' workstation now a relic of the past ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [the answer from Chrome help](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=1220892) article:

You'll need Mac OS 10.5 and Mac OS 10.6 (recommended).
*10.7 I believe is also supported.*

If you have the following graphics cards, WebGL is *unsupported* and is disabled by default:

- NVIDIA GeForce FX Go5200
- ATI Radeon HD2400
- ATI Radeon 2600 series
- ATI Radeon X1900
- GeForce 7300 GT

So, yes, [upgrade videocard](http://xlr8yourmac.com/video.html#cards) for WebGL to work.